# Dispatching Action on the component button of React Native

Tags: react-native

I am relatively new in React Native and I tried to read a lot of tutorials everywhere, still I don't get the proper solution on my issue. What is the proper way of calling the action clearCart() and at the same time navigate? I am having this error regarding the dispatch when pressed the button.

It seems I use componentDidMount() or useEffect() and separately call the clearCart() but I would gladly welcome any suggestions as it will be additional for me.

```
//other imports
import {clearCart} from 'src/modules/cart/actions';
//other imports..

class WebviewPayment extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    const {route} = props;
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      uri: route?.params?.uri ?? '',
    };
  }
  
  handleContinue = () => {
    const {navigation, dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(clearCart());
    navigation.pop();
    navigation.navigate(homeTabs.shop);
  };

  //other components here

  render() {
    const {loading, uri} = this.state;
    const {t} = this.props;
    return (
      <ThemedView isFullView>
        <WebView
          source={{uri}}
          onNavigationStateChange={data => this.handleResponse(data)}
          style={styles.webView}
          onLoadStart={() => this.setState({loading: false})}
        />
        {loading && (
          <View style={styles.viewLoading}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black"/>
          </View>
        )}
        <Container style={styles.footer}>
          <Button
            title={t('cart:text_shopping')}
            onPress={this.handleContinue}
          />
        </Container>
      </ThemedView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  webView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  viewLoading: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  footer: {
    marginVertical: margin.big,
  },
});

WebviewPayment.propTypes = {};

export default withTranslation()(WebviewPayment);
```

In my **actions.js**, I have:

```
export function clearCart() {
  return {
    type: Actions.CLEAR_CART,
  };
}
```

Comment: you need use  react-redux connect.  https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: can you show the error message?

Comment: This is the error I am getting. [link](https://i.ibb.co/ysFmDGW/Capture.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now and this might help others in case they come across with the same issue as mine. The working code is as follow:

```
//other imports
import {clearCart} from 'src/modules/cart/actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
//other imports..

class WebviewPayment extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    const {route} = props;
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      uri: route?.params?.uri ?? '',
    };
  }
  
  handleContinue = () => {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    this.props.clearCart();
    navigation.pop();
    navigation.navigate(homeTabs.shop);
  };

  //other components here

  render() {
    const {loading, uri} = this.state;
    const {t} = this.props;
    return (
      <ThemedView isFullView>
        <WebView
          source={{uri}}
          onNavigationStateChange={data => this.handleResponse(data)}
          style={styles.webView}
          onLoadStart={() => this.setState({loading: false})}
        />
        {loading && (
          <View style={styles.viewLoading}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black"/>
          </View>
        )}
        <Container style={styles.footer}>
          <Button
            title={t('cart:text_shopping')}
            onPress={this.handleContinue}
          />
        </Container>
      </ThemedView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  webView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  viewLoading: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  footer: {
    marginVertical: margin.big,
  },
});

WebviewPayment.propTypes = {};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  clearCart: () => dispatch(clearCart()),
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withTranslation()(WebviewPayment));
```

I used react-redux **connect** then **mapDispatchToProps** to pass the clearCart() into props.